# How to create clone for tabbarpage in tabcontroladv?

Tags: c#, winforms, syncfusion

How can I crate a clone for tabbarpage in tabcontroladv?

I have created the clone but changing the parent controls gets reflected in cloned control. I need both the parent and cloned control should be seperated.
I have used the below codes:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabPage newPage = new TabPage();
    foreach (Control c in  tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls)
    {
        Control cNew = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(c.GetType());

        PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(c);

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor entry in pdc)
        {
            object val = entry.GetValue(c);
            entry.SetValue(cNew, val);
        }
        newPage.Controls.Add(cNew);
    }

    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newPage);
}
```

After the clone is created the change in parent controls gets reflected in cloned cotrol.

Can i have a sample for this?? how to create a clone. the change in parent should not get reflected to cloned control.

Comment: Can this issue be recreated with normal WinForm TabControl/TabPage?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to clone controls in TabBarPage as the changes in parent TabBarPage should not get reflected to cloned TabBarPage.

TabBarPage newPage;

```
// To Copy
newPage = new TabBarPage();
foreach (Control c in this.tabBarSplitterControl1.ActivePage.Controls)
{
    Control cNew = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(c.GetType());

    PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(c);

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor entry in pdc)
    {
        object val = entry.GetValue(c);
        entry.SetValue(cNew, val);
    }
    newPage.Controls.Add(cNew);
}
newPage.Text = "New Tab";

// To Paste
this.tabBarSplitterControl1.TabBarPages.Add(newPage);
```

Sample Link: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/Cloning964503659.zip